# How to get paremeters required by Opennebula XML-RPC api

Tags: python, virtual-machine, xml-rpc, opennebula

I am trying to create a VM using Opennebula XML-RPC API. That shouldn't be a problem, according to their [documentation](https://docs.opennebula.io/5.12/integration/system_interfaces/api.html#onevm).

However, parameters required for this method are nowhere to be seen (as well as for all other methods).

So far, I have managed to list all VMs, by diving into Opennebula CLI scripts and finding that `onevm list` (`one.vmpool.info` in context of pyone) requires 4 parameters that have to be integers:

```
In [1]: import pyone
In [2]: one = pyone.OneServer('http://oneserver:2633/RPC2', session='admin:pass')
In [3]: one.vmpool.info(-1, -1, -1, -1)
Out[3]: <pyone.bindings.VM_POOLSub at 0x103be9190>
```

This approach is quite ridiculous, however.

I'm sure there is a way to get the required RPC method parameters more easily, I just can't find one.

Hoping for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters for IN and OUT are located in the documentation link you mentioned - https://docs.opennebula.io/6.0/integration_and_development/system_interfaces/api.html#actions-for-templates-management

You can find all the necessary parameters here. In case you still have issues, do let me know!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).